# matplot lib axis confusion mapping strings to axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I'm really confused at the output of my code below. The plot looks like this[image: plot]

```
for i in range(0,300):
    test = random.random()
    if test < .10:
        plot_data.append(('filler','Octagon',random.random()))
    elif test >= .10 and test <= .40:
        plot_data.append(('filler','Rectangle',random.random()))
    elif test > .40 and test <= .70:
        plot_data.append(('filler','Circle',random.random()))
    elif test > .70 and test <= 1:
        plot_data.append(('filler','Hexagon',random.random()))

fig = plt.figure()
N=100
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)



x = [data_point[1] for data_point in plot_data]
x_vals = ["Rectangle","Hexagon","Octagon","Circle"]
y =[data_point[2] for data_point in plot_data]

print(x)
ax.scatter(x, y, color = rgb)

plt.xticks(range(len(x_vals)),x_vals)
plt.xlabel("Polygon")
plt.ylabel("RGB Color Value")

plt.show()
```

The print statement in the middle of the code showing the values of what I assumed to be on the x axis are this

```
['Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Octagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Octagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Octagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Octagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Octagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Octagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Octagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Octagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Octagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Octagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Octagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Octagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Octagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Octagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle', 'Hexagon', 'Rectangle', 'Circle']
```

The reason I show the output is just to show that it seems for whatever reason, the Circle and Octagon seem to be getting mixed up. There should be many less Octagon labels than Circles. I have no idea why the plot is mislabeled, and could not find anything online about it. I need the x axis to stay in this order of shapes. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

For reference plot_data is a tuple that looks like

```
(array_of_unimportance, string shape_classifier(i.e. "Rectangle"), float rgb_val range(0,1.0))
```

Comment: @Mr.T yes, poor naming on my part. Plot data are the actual points on the graph, while data is just used to create the color scheme. I've removed "data" since it's not important to the problem at hand

Comment: Without knowing the structure of plot_data, there is little one can say, I guess. Basically, you have to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Mr.T I've updated it at the bottom of the answer. x is a list of strings that are shapes, either rectangle,circle,square, or hexagon, and y is a float between 0.0 to 1.0

Comment: The problem seems to be that you overwrite your x-axis labels but it is hard to say without a reproducible dataset.  Why four categories in your sample output are filled with data, when you only have three categories, is beyond me.

Comment: @Mr.T I have 4 categories but octagon is used much less than Circle. I believe the two are switched in the labels but I cannot figure out why. I have created a code sample that allows you to test yourself and edited the question.

Comment: Before anything else, could you update matplotlib to version 2.2.2? That would allow to set any required order on the categories and would allow to remove the `plt.xticks` line, which causes the confusion here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am using 2.2.2 but didn't see anywhere how to set an order of categories with it

Comment: You're right, you cannot (currently) set the order directly, but implicitely, by providing the data in the correct order you are aiming at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `xticks` just sets the tick positions and labels, it will not reorder the data.
Since the categories are placed in the order of appearence on the axis, their order may not coincide with the desired order by default. A trick is to first let the axis know the desired order by plotting something in that order to it and later remove it. When then plotting the data, the order stays.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = ['Octagon', 'Hexagon', 'Circle', 'Rectangle', 'Hexagon', 'Circle']
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

# the desired order of categories along the axis:
order=["Rectangle", "Hexagon", "Octagon", "Circle"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#plot some artist first to define order of axis and remove again.
s = ax.scatter(order, y[:len(order)])
s.remove()
# Then plot real values
ax.scatter(x,y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I usually plot NaN values. No need to remove them and afaik they don't interfere with the graph. Or is there any situation, where they could disturb the plot?

Comment: @Mr.T You may use `s = ax.scatter(order, np.empty(len(order))*np.nan)` and then not remove anything. I don't think they hurt, but of course you have an extra artist in `ax.collections` and need to remember it being there for no reason, once this is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by mapping ["Circle", "Octagon", "Hexagon", "Rectangle"] to integer values between 0,1 with plt.xticks(). It is not ideal but works. If anyone is having a similar issue my code is below. I will leave this question unmarked for a while if anyone has a better solution.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
key = {"Circle":0, "Octagon":0.4,"Hexagon":0.6,"Rectangle":1}


x =[key[data_point[1]] for data_point in plot_data]
y =[data_point[2] for data_point in plot_data]
x_vals = ["Circle","Octagon","Hexagon","Rectangle"]

plt.xticks([0,0.4,0.6,1.0],x_vals)
plt.xlabel("Polygon")
plt.ylabel("RGB Color Value")
ax.scatter(x, y)

plt.show()
```